# Redux saga not listening to action triggered from icon click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

**Saga declaration**

```
function* DoStuffInSaga({myRef}){
    try {
        console.info("saga running");

        return yield delay(1000, 1);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}

export function* mySaga(){
    yield all([
        yield takeLatest(DO_STUFF_ACTION, DoStuffInSaga)
    ]);
}
```

**Saga exposed from index.js**

```
export { mySaga } from './mySaga';
```

**Saga init**

```
import * as sagas from './';

const initSagas = (sagaMiddleware) => {
    (Object.keys(sagas).map(key => sagas[key])||[]).forEach(sagaMiddleware.run.bind(sagaMiddleware));
}

export default initSagas;
```

If I log Object.keys(sagas), the saga is mentioned in the list, so I'd think the Saga has started.

this function is called from the store:

```
initSagas(sagaMiddleWare);
```

**Action call**

I have a presentation component that does this:

```
import { doStuff } from '../../actions';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: () => dispatch(doStuff())
    };
}
```

Where *doStuff* is:

```
export const DO_STUFF_ACTION = 'DO_STUFF_ACTION';

export function doStuff(myRef) {
    console.info('At doStuff action', myRef);
    return { type: DO_STUFF_ACTION, myRef };
}
```

That action is called from a material UI icon click:

```
import { doStuff } from '../../actions';

function DoStuff(){
    doStuff('my-ref-key');
}

<Print className={classes.iconWithText} onClick={DoStuff} />
```

**My question**

> "At doStuff action" is being logged, it looks (to me) like the Saga should be running, yet it does not appear to be listening to the action coming in, because the saga doesn't log anything.
>   What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

> It has to do with the way the desired action is being called. Right now it's triggered on an icon click, if I trigger it on `componentDidMount` of the current page component, the saga is called just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but this is the part that looks funny to me:

```
export function* mySaga(){
    yield all([
        yield takeLatest(DO_STUFF_ACTION, DoStuffInSaga)
    ]);
}
```

The [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/) shows `takeLatest` being used like this:

```
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser);
}
```

So I'd expect yours to look similar:

```
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest(DO_STUFF_ACTION, DoStuffInSaga);
}
```

Comment: Doing the saga like the last code block doesn't change anything. That `all` bit is code a colleague wrote (he's on vacation). Isn't that like C# `await Task.WhenAll`? You could argue that it's useless with just one yield, but omitting it doesn't seem to change anything.